# Gerund with you or your

Tags: gerunds

What is the correct form:
" I can't bear the thought of YOUR going out" or "I can't bear the thought of YOU going out".

Comment: They're both good. Perhaps, the first emphasises the 'going out', while the second emphasises 'you' (as opposed to me, him her or them).